# Debugging, dynamic code is different from source

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I'm working with Sharepoint product in Visual Studio 2013. There is one code file, that I tried to put some changes in, when I hit debug and reach that point, where the changes should be, then there are no changes at all..

That means, that Dynamic code is same as it was, but when I stop debug and look at code, then changes are still there.

To be more precise, it is JavaScript file, which is custom made.

I tried:

Clean --> Build --> Rebuild

Close IE completely (in case of some cache files)

Restart Visual Studio

At the moment, I am out of ideas, what to do...

Comment: Did you actually clear the browser cache and not just open and close it?

Comment: Apparently I didn't, thanks for remark! :)